# How do I use a service property in a route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

I have a service that handles user authentication and gets the user data via a model. One of the pieces of data that it fetches is a date for the start of a dietary program. I want to use this date to calculate a number: the number of days since the start of the program, so I can use that number to query a different model that pulls content from a CMS.

I haven't been able to access that number anywhere other than a template.

**This is the Controller for Dashboard**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  authManager: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    });
```

**This is the template**

```
{{#if authManager.currentUser.activeCleanse}}
  You are on a cleanse that starts 
{{authManager.currentUser.cleanse_start}}
  {{else}}
  You are not on a cleanse.
{{/if}}
```

All of the above code works, but when I try something like this in the controller:

```
  activeCleanse: Ember.computed( function(){
    return this.get('authManager.currentUser').then( (user) => {
    return user.cleanse_active;
    }.bind(this))
  }),

  startDate: Ember.computed( function(){
    return this.get('authManager.currentUser').then( (user) => {
    return user.cleanse_start;
    }.bind(this))
  })
```

And replace the template with:

```
{{#if activeCleanse}}
  You are on a cleanse that starts {{startDate}}
  {{else}}
  You are not on a cleanse.
{{/if}}
```

It doesn't respond to `activeCleanse` being false (the template only seems to be checking for its existence) and the date tag only shows `[object Object]`.

I am actually trying to get the date in the controller so I can manipulate it to pass as one of the parameters to the dashboard route, which gets a model based on the specific day:

**The Dashboard Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.get('store').queryRecord('cleanse-post', {
      filter: {
        tag: 'day-1'
        }
      });
    },

});
```

I want to be able to dynamically set the tag for the filter based on the calculation for the date.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I've been going in circles with this and I have no idea what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `activeCleanse` it's computed property depends on `authManager.currentUser`,so your computed property format should be like this

```
     activeCleanse: Ember.computed('authManager.currentUser',function(){
      //return the result
     }),
```

There is no need for `bind(this)` since that computed property will be called with particular context, in your example `this` would be controller.

2. Currently your computed property is returning Promise, computed property is not promise aware. you can try returning `DS.PromiseObject` to make it work.

```
    activeCleanse:Ember.computed(function(){
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
          promise: this.get('authManager.currentUser').then( (user) => {
            return user.cleanse_start;
          })
      })
```

In your case, I would say you can use setupController hook on the route, where you can set `activeCleanse` property,

```
this.get('authManager.currentUser').then( (user) => {
  this.set('activeCleanse,user.cleanse_active);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but your solution doesn't seem to work. The `setupController()` hook doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Now the template doesn't even recognize the existence of the `activeCleanse` property. I also tried having the controller return a promise, but that didn't get any results either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the code you'd provided. I put that into the controller and now I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined`. No idea what that is referring to but the controller is all that has changed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I updated code in the second point. I am not aware of what this Promise `this.get('authManager.currentUser')`  will return. Just ensure you are receiving the `user.cleanse_start` is corretly.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because ultimately the issue came down to handling the promise object, and I want to provide a bit more detail for people that might see this. In order to do what I wanted, we actually used the `didInsertElement` hook, then use the `this.get('authManager.currentUeser).then ( (user) => {...}` This allowed us to make a datastore call in the resolution of the promise in order to use the information from the user model in filtering the call to `store`. A bit weird but it worked. Thanks for you help @kumkanillam